# What is the best way to make a deep reinforcement learning environment with a continuous 2D action space?

Tags: machine-learning, reinforcement-learning, keras

I understand that the actor-critic method is probably where I want to start because of how it works with continuous action spaces.

However, the problem I am trying to solve would require the action be a vector of 11 continuous values. When I go to design my training environment and the architecture of my DRL network, I am not sure how to map a vector of values to the state for the state-action pairs.

I am trying to use this article as a jumping off point, but I am not sure where to go: https://medium.com/@asteinbach/actor-critic-using-deep-rl-continuous-mountain-car-in-tensorflow-4c1fb2110f7c